# Tablesorter Set output widget options on the fly

Tags: javascript, widget, output, html-table, tablesorter

I'm using the tablesorter fork from Mottie. I am not very experienced with javascript, but so far I got everything to work. Here is the problem:
NOW I want to have two buttons above my table to allow the download of either all rows or download just the selected rows.

For this I have the following javascript code which works partly. I just need to get it to work to download all(!) rows.

What I am doing wrong ?

Here is the portion which outputs all:

```
$('.downloadall').click(function(){
    var $table = $('.tablesorter');
    wo = $table[0].config.widgetOptions,
    saved = $table.find('.output-filter-all :checked').attr('class');
    wo.output_includeHTML  = false;
    wo.output_delivery = 'p';
    // d = download p = page
    wo.output_saveRows ='a';
    // a = all f=filtered
    $table.trigger('outputTable');
    return false;
});
```

This works very well including the setting of all the other output options.
The following code does exactly the same thing, but I want, of course, just the selected rows.

```
$('.downloadselected').click(function(){
    var $table = $('.tablesorter');
    wo = $table[0].config.widgetOptions,
    saved = $table.find('.output-filter-all :checked').attr('class');
    wo.output_includeHTML  = false;
    wo.output_delivery = 'p';
    // d = download p = page
    wo.output_saveRows = saved;
    // a = all f=filtered
    $table.trigger('outputTable');
    return false;
});
```

I've tried various things but with no luck.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Is `.output-filter-all` the class name of the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just overlooked that the class name '.saved' is of course not correct. At the end Mottie pointed me to the right direction. Here is the solution to my original question just use the correct class name .checked and everthing works as expected.:

```js
$('.downloadselected').click(function(){
  var $this =$('#table');
  var $table = $('.tablesorter');
   wo = $table[0].config.widgetOptions,
   wo.output_includeHTML  = false;
   wo.output_delivery = 'p';
   // d = download p = page
   //saved = '.checked';
   // a = all f=filtered
    wo.output_saveRows = '.checked';
    $table.trigger('outputTable');
    return false;
});
```

It

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't tell what to expect from the table HTML. I don't know what the `saved` variable ends up as, but it appears to be missing the leading period to make a jQuery selector for a class name.

```
wo.output_saveRows = '.' + saved;
```

Anyway, it got me thinking that currently you can't select a row based on its content, so I updated the `saveRows` option to now accept a [filter callback function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) which as of this writing is currently only available in the [master branch](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-output.js), and can be used as follows:

```
$('.downloadselected').click(function(){
    var $table = $('.tablesorter'),
      wo = $table[0].config.widgetOptions
    wo.output_includeHTML  = false;
    wo.output_delivery = 'p';
    wo.output_saveRows = function(){
        // include row only if it has a checked checkbox
        return $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0;
    };
    $table.trigger('outputTable');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have taken portions of your code based on the output widget example page from here: [link](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html). There the download dialog selects which rows are output (Filtered, Visible,Seelcted, Sel+Vis, All) I just want  to make this selected predefined instead of a dialog.

Comment: Here is the relevant html code I use:
`code`
<tr> <td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr> 
for the first column and 
<TD class="cellClass" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt;text-align:left">Names</td> 
for the "data"rows.